# similarity metric used by the Naive Bayes classifier under Weka

Tags: machine-learning, similarity, bayesian, metric

I want to know The similarity metric used by the Naive Bayes classifier under Weka.
any help?

Answer (score 1):

Naive Bayes doesn't use any metric. It is a probability classifier

Comment: So, how it compares two documents?  Is it not necessary to have a similarity measure to compare two documents?

Comment: What are understanding under "Documents" in this case?

Comment: you can use MS Word or Workshare

Comment: > you can use MS Word or Workshare                                       what?

Comment: >... to compare two documents?